# The exterior product in the Hopf algebra

Tags: hopf-algebras

Here is a exercise in the Eiichi Abe's book Hopf Algebras, Ex2.4,Ch2, [p.83](http://books.google.com/books?id=D0AIcewz5-8C&pg=PA83).

If $X$ is a left coideal, show that $X\wedge Y$ is a right coideal and that $X\subset X\wedge Y$.

Maybe you can explain the $X\wedge Y$ in the Hopf algebra, does it has any geometry meaning?

Comment: This is not the exterior product.